# Altair tooltips don't work when using selection

Tags: python, tooltip, selection, altair

I am trying to use a vertical rule similar to the one shown on the altair multi-line tooltip example here https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/multiline_tooltip.html. I would like to use text tooltips too, as my dataset contains text comments that are relevant to each point.

Here is the example code, to which I added a "comments" column with dummy text, and I also added the tooltips to the line component, but the tooltips don't work.

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
source = pd.DataFrame(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(100, 3), 0).round(2),
                    columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=pd.RangeIndex(100, name='x'))
source = source.reset_index().melt('x', var_name='category', value_name='y')
```

I added this line to create a coment column:

```
source['comments']='comment'+source.category+source.x.apply(str)
```

```
# Create a selection that chooses the nearest point & selects based on x-value
nearest = alt.selection(type='single', nearest=True, on='mouseover',
                        fields=['x'], empty='none')

# The basic line
```

I added tooltips here:

```
line = alt.Chart(source).mark_line(interpolate='basis').encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='y:Q',
    color='category:N',tooltip='comments'
)
```

And the rest of the code:

```
# Transparent selectors across the chart. This is what tells us
# the x-value of the cursor
selectors = alt.Chart(source).mark_point().encode(
    x='x:Q',
    opacity=alt.value(0),
).add_selection(
    nearest
)

# Draw points on the line, and highlight based on selection
points = line.mark_point().encode(
    opacity=alt.condition(nearest, alt.value(1), alt.value(0))
)

# Draw text labels near the points, and highlight based on selection
text = line.mark_text(align='left', dx=5, dy=-5).encode(
    text=alt.condition(nearest, 'y:Q', alt.value(' '))
)

# Draw a rule at the location of the selection
rules = alt.Chart(source).mark_rule(color='gray').encode(
    x='x:Q',
).transform_filter(
    nearest
)

# Put the five layers into a chart and bind the data
alt.layer(
    line, selectors, points, rules, text
).properties(
    width=600, height=300
)
```

If you run this code, it won't show tooltips. To see the tooltips I have to get rid of the selection, so to display the chart at the end and see the tooltips, but not the rule, I would have to do:

```
alt.layer(line).properties(width=600, height=300)
```

How can I have both, tooltips and rule?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in Vega-Lite; see [vega-lite#5732](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/5732).

To get around it, you can add a selection to each layer that does not already have one; e.g.

```python
text = line.mark_text(align='left', dx=5, dy=-5).encode(
    text=alt.condition(nearest, 'y:Q', alt.value(' '))
).add_selection(alt.selection_single())
```

Then your tooltip will behave the same whether the layer is shown individually or in the layered chart.

Semi-related note: putting a tooltip on a line chart is probably not what you want (it generates one tooltip per line mark). Try putting your tooltip on the rule mark instead; see [Pivot Transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/pivot.html#pivot-transform) examples for an example of a tooltip like this.

Comment: Thank you! Added single selection to the ruler only and that enabled the tooltips for the example. It didn't work for the real dataset I'm working on because it has three different dataframes overlaid with different types of data each. I tried pivot too, but have not arrived to a satisfactory solution.

Comment: The pivot transform is an excellent tip.